# How do I remove certain lines (using line numbers) in a file?

Tags: text-processing

There are specific lines that I want to remove from a file. Let's say it's line 20-37 and then line 45. How would I do that without specifying the content of those lines?

Comment: How big is your file? Could it be loaded into memory?

Comment: A few kilobytes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With `sed`, like so:

```
sed '20,37d; 45d' < input.txt > output.txt
```

If you wanted to do this in-place:

```
sed --in-place '20,37d; 45d' file.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it in-place?

Comment: I suggest sed -i file

Comment: @Tshepang: Use `ed`, or GNU sed `-i`, or [`sponge`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9318/9324#9324), or a [large file method](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11067).

Comment: I've often wondered about the possibly misleading term **in-place**, when referring to 'sed', so I looked it up in 'man sed': *--in-place[=SUFFIX]*  `This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.` ... I don't know about any other 'sed' but the logistics of updating "in place" with a *stream* editor don't "compute" :)

Comment: Most "in-place" methods use a temporary file, in my experience.

Comment: @fred If you use a full-screen text editor to modify the file are you editing a file in-place?  Most editors including Vim use the same logic in-place sed uses.

Comment: Keep in mind the temporary file "in-place" method of sed usually does not work correctly with links of any sort.  You may end up overwriting the link with an edited copy of the file, leaving the original in place.

Answer (score 5):

If the file fits comfortably in memory, you could also use `ed`.
The commands are quite similar to the `sed` one above with one *notable difference*: you have to pass the list of line numbers/ranges to be deleted in descending order (from the highest line no/range to the lowest one). The reason is that when you delete/insert/split/join lines with `ed`, the text buffer is updated after each subcommand so if you delete some lines, the rest of the following lines will no longer be at the same position in the buffer when the next subcommand is executed. So you have to start backwards<sup>1</sup>.
*In-place* editing:

```
ed -s in_file <<IN
45d
20,37d
w
q
IN
```

or

```
ed -s in_file <<< $'45d\n20,37d\nw\nq\n'
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' 45d 20,37d w q | ed -s in_file
```

Replace `w`rite with `,p`rint if you want to print the resulting output instead of writing to file. If you want to keep the original file intact and write to another file you can pass the new file name to the `w`rite subcommand:

```
ed -s in_file <<IN
78,86d
65d
51d
20,37d
w out_file
q
IN
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
Unless you are willing to calculate the new line numbers after each `d`elete, which is quite trivial for this particular case (after deleting lines 20-37, i.e. 18 lines, line 45 becomes line 27) so you could run:

```
ed -s in_file <<IN
20,37d
27d
w
q
IN
```

However, if you have to delete multiple line numbers/ranges, working backwards is a no-brainer.

Comment: Is the `q` command useful at the end? I guess it exits either way.

Comment: @TomFenech - not all implementations exit either way (though most do...I can no longer find the thread where this was discussed...)

Answer (score 1):

Just read it into memory, alter it, then write it back. You can do something like

```
filename = "foo"
f = open(filename, 'r+')                                                                                                                                 
linenums = [1, 3]                                                                                                                                            
s = [y for x, y in enumerate(f) if x not in [line-1 for line in linenums]]                                                                                                                                          
f.seek(0)
f.write(''.join(s))
f.truncate(f.tell())
f.close()
```

Tested with a 5 line file. Credits to http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/fileaccess.html, see section "Modifying a File in Place Without a Temporary File". See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python

Some notes:

1. One could first truncate the file,
   then write to it, rather than write,
   then truncate, as above. However, I
   don't know of a Python flag that
   allows one to read, and then do a
   truncated write. But maybe I'm
   missing something, as the document
   isn't all that clear. Which brings
   me to
2. Sometimes the Python docs really
   suck. See
   http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

   > Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (note that 'w+'
   >   truncates the file).

   Does this mean anything to you? What
   the hell is "open for updating"?
3. I don't know if doing this in python
   as opposed to something unixy like
   the stream editor is better. It
   might be more portable, but I don't
   know how portable sed is. I just
   wrote it like that because I'm more
   comfortable with low level
   programming than using classic unix
   tools, which are good if they do
   exactly what you want, but (I think)
   are generally less flexible.
4. This approach (manipulating the file in memory)
   trades memory for disk
   space. It should work Ok on machines
   with a few Gb of memory for files up
   to a few hundred Mb. Python doesn't
   handle strings very efficiently, so
   switching to C/C++ for example would
   slightly increase performance and
   greatly reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '20,37d|45d|x' file
```

1. `d` delete
2. `x` save and close