# How to prevent from destroying symlinks, using Perl when to replace with sed regex?

Tags: sed, perl, symlink, replace

Based on [How do I prevent sed -i from destroying symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192012/how-do-i-prevent-sed-i-from-destroying-symlinks), but I use Perl.

I tried by middle of all these questions:

- [Is there a way to make perl -i not clobber symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9318/is-there-a-way-to-make-perl-i-not-clobber-symlinks)
- [perl symlink on gz file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464550/perl-symlink-on-gz-file)
- [How do I prevent sed from destroying hardinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305661/how-do-i-prevent-sed-from-destroying-hardinks)

It was unsucessfull. Here is the little and simple sample:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

while (<>) 
{

  ## For all lines, replace all occurrences of #5c616c with another colour
  s/#5c616c/#8bbac9/g $(readlink -e -- "<>")

  ## $(readlink -e -- "<>") is similar to --in-place --follow-symlinks

  ## Print the line
  print;
}
```

Comment: The first link solution you point out is particularly interesting for not having to complicate code.

Comment: The codes in Shell are easy than in Perl, but I am not sure it is possible to make something similar in Shell to that in Perl. See the answer of [terdon](@terdon): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492724/232293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readlink -e` command is not portable so should not be relied upon.

```
$ cat input
Like quills upon the fretful porpentine.
$ ln -s input alink
$ readlink -e alink
readlink: illegal option -- e
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
```

Within the Perl code, instead replace the links with the filename it points to using [Perl's `readlink` function](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readlink) then loop over the input as usual.

```
$ perl -i -ple 'BEGIN{for(@ARGV){ $_=readlink if -l }} tr/A-Z/a-z/' alink
```

`alink` is still a symbolic link and the contents of `input` have been modified:

```
$ perl -E 'say readlink "alink"'
input
$ cat input
LIKE QUILLS UPON THE FRETFUL PORPENTINE.
```

Within a Perl script this might look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    $arg = readlink $arg if -l $arg;
}

# in-place edit with backup filename, perldoc -v '$^I'
$^I = ".whoops";

while (readline) {
    s/#5c616c/#8bbac9/g;
    print;
}
```

though may need `List::Util::uniq` or similar to avoid modifying the same filename two or more times, if the input contains duplicate filenames.

Comment: What if `<>` is necessary? See the first codes lines of [terdon](@terdon): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492724/232293.

Comment: `<>` is a less readable way to say `readline`. compare `perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '<>;readline'`

Comment: Hi, I have tested it, it almost worked - it preserved the symlinks, but it made all unusual. You can download the small archive file: https://transfernow.net/f07ahfb8joa4 and test by yourself.